# how do i get subclass UIButton title in superclass objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, inheritance

Here is my code.

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController{

}
-(void) initCallService;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
-(void) initCallService{

}
@end
```

other class which is sub class of above

```
@interface DetailViewController : MasterViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
}
@end


@implementation DetailViewController
-(void) btntitle_changed{
    [btn setTitle:[self.arr objectAtIndex:recordIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

I need whenever the title changes in `btntitle_changed` method of `DetailViewController` class to send it to `MasterViewController`'s `initCallService` method. I don't know how can i achieve this with the class hierarchy. Can anyone guide me for this ? Valid answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question. What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: needed a property `NSString *buttonTitle` in MasterVC, `[super setButtonTitle:btn.title]`

Comment: I need the btn(which is defined in DetailViewController) title in MasterViewController's "initCallService" method

Comment: Thanks annop vaidya for answering. But i wont it without declaring nsstring in MasterVC. is it possible ?

Comment: Your concept/class-design is wrong. If you need something from a subclass in a superclass, you are violating inheritance laws. A correct design would implement the button as a property on the superclass (which needs the title) and also define a method `btnChanged` which could send a notification or use an instance-variable to save the title. Subclasses would then have to call `[super btnChanged]` in their implementation.

Comment: @ViralNarshana: then where are you planning to store the value. As you must have seen my answer.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya  can i do this with objective c categories ?

Comment: @ViralNarshana: category will add method, even a property can be added, but that is against your policy!!! In the method what and where will you store the string, do you need to pass the string to something like textfield, button title, xml, json, core data etc?

Comment: I hope NSNotificationCenter may work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a property in MasterViewController say `NSString *buttonTitle`

```
-(void) btntitle_changed{
    [btn setTitle:[self.arr objectAtIndex:recordIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [super setButtonTitle:btn.title];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anoop Vaidya for such a nice help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by setting a Protocol

in your DetailViewController.h

```
         @protocol TitleChange <NSObject>
          -(void)initCallService:(NSString *)title;
         @end
```

and set a property as

```
      @property(nonatomic,assign) id <TitleChange> delegate;

      In DetailViewController.m

     -(void) btntitle_changed
       {
      [btn setTitle:[self.arr objectAtIndex:recordIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.delegate initCallservice: btn.title]
       }
```

In your MasterViewContoller.h add TitleChange delegate as

```
    @interface MasterViewController : UIViewController<TitleChange>{

    }
```

In you MasterViewContoller.m while initiating DetailViewController

```
    DetailViewController *vc =[[DetailViewController alloc] :@"DetailViewController"   bundle:nil];
    vc.delegate=self
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this is how you Protocol and delegates which is widely used for passing data and just go through the basics of it

Comment: the reason is the same i stated in the other protocol-answer: it's a good idea for general inter-object-communication, but not for class-hierarchies. the subclass would essentially end up being its own delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `-(void)initCallService` to `-(void)initCallServiceWithButtonTitle:(NSSTring*)title`.
Then change `btntitle_changed` function as follows:

```
-(void) btntitle_changed{
    [btn setTitle:[self.arr objectAtIndex:recordIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [super initCallServiceWithButtonTitle:btn.title];
}

-(void)initCallServiceWithButtonTitle:(NSString*)title{
 //do whatever you want with 'title'
}
```